# How to capture video from camera via ethernet socket

Tags: c++, qt

I need to capture video from a live camera plugged to my PC ethernet socket. I used Phonon to capture video from a file in my system first. It works fine. Then, I created a socket to read the video. Here, I do not know how to get the buffered data and set it as a source to my Phonon video! I would thank if anyone could help me with this.

Here's the code to read a video :

```
void PlayVideo::rollOn()
   {
   media = new Phonon::MediaObject(movieLabel);
   media->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(QString("/home/saman/4.7/phonon_test/sample.mp4")));
   videoPlayer = new Phonon::VideoPlayer(Phonon::VideoCategory, movieLabel);
   videoPlayer->setFixedSize(QSize(400, 300));
   videoPlayer->show();
   connect(videoPlayer, SIGNAL(finished()), videoPlayer, SLOT(deleteLater()));
   videoPlayer->play(media->currentSource());
   }
```

and this is how I added sockets to the code:

```
  void PlayVideo::rollOn()
   {
   udpSocketin = new QUdpSocket(this);
   udpSocketin->bind(localPort);
   connect(udpSocketin, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(readDatagrams()));
   QDataStream out(&datagramout, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
   out.setVersion (QDataStream::Qt_4_7);
   timer2 = new QTimer(this);
   connect(timer2, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(playbuff()));
   media = new Phonon::MediaObject(movieLabel);
   media->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(QString("/home/saman/4.7/phonon_test/sample.mp4")));

   //media->setCurrentSource (Phonon::MediaSource());
   videoPlayer = new Phonon::VideoPlayer(Phonon::VideoCategory, movieLabel);     
   videoPlayer->setFixedSize(QSize(400, 300));     
   videoPlayer->show();     
   connect(videoPlayer, SIGNAL(finished()), videoPlayer, SLOT(deleteLater()));     
   videoPlayer->play(media->currentSource());
   }    
   void PlayVideo::readDatagrams()
   {
   if(udpSocketin->hasPendingDatagrams ())
   {
   datagramin.resize (udpSocketin->pendingDatagramSize ());
   qint64 receiveBytes = udpSocketin->readDatagram (datagramin.data (), datagramin.size ));
   if(receivedBytes <= 0)
   {
   qDebug("receivedBytes <= 0");
   }
```

}
}

Comment: in the future, you can high light your code and hit ctrl-k to get stackOverFlow to make code blocks (assuming that you did 4 spaces for each line on here).

Answer (score 1):

You can put your data into a `QBuffer`, which is a subclass of `QIODevice`. Then, there's a media source constructor that accepts a `QIODevice`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to interpret your question, is your socket a QSocket? QSocket also implements QIODevice, so you can pass it directly to a Phonon::MediaSource...